# How do I use sed to replace with cat file content

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I tried the following code, but it doesn't do what I want:

```
echo "include(file.txt)" | sed -E 's/include\(([^)]+)\)/'$(cat $(readlink -f /tmp/$1))'/g'
```

I need replace some special words with file content. This is similar "include" function of the PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed, you can use the `e` modifier to **e**xecute the replacement pattern after substitution:

> e
>
> This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern space. If a substitution was made, the command that is found
> in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its
> output. A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the
> command to be executed contains a NUL character. This is a GNU sed
> extension.

Ex. given

```
$ cat /tmp/file.txt
foo bar
baz
```

then

```
$ echo "include(file.txt)" | sed -E 's:include\(([^)]+)\):cat /tmp/\1:e'
foo bar
baz
```

or (not sure why you need `readlink` here)

```
$ echo "include(file.txt)" | sed -E 's:include\(([^)]+)\):cat "$(readlink -f "/tmp/\1")":e'
foo bar
baz
```

Note that it is *the whole pattern space* resulting from the successful substitution that is executed, and that it is executed by `/bin/sh` (so you need to avoid "bashisms").